# Testing 7-Zip archives from a python script

Tags: python, archive, 7zip

So I've got a python script that, at it's core, makes .7z archives of selected directories for the purpose of backing up data. For simplicty sake I've simply invoked 7-zip through the windows command line, like so:

```
def runcompressor(target, contents):
print("Compressing {}...".format(contents))
archive = currentmodule
archive += "{}\\{}.7z".format(target, target)
os.system('7z u "{}" "{}" -mx=9 -mmt=on -ssw -up1q0r2x2y2z1w2'.format(archive, contents))
print("Done!")
```

Which creates a new archive if one doesn't exist and updates the old one if it does, but if something goes wrong the archive will be corrupted, and if this command hits an existing, corrupted archive, it just gives up. Now 7zip has a command for testing the integrity of an archive, but the documentation says nothing about giving an output, and then comes the trouble of capturing that output in python.

Is there a way I can test the archives first, to determine if they've been corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `7z` executable returns a value of two or greater if it encounters a problem. In a batch script, you would generally use `errorlevel` to detect this. Unfortunately, `os.system()` under Windows gives the return value of the command interpreter used to run your program, not the exit value of your program itself.

If you want the latter, you'll probably going to have to get your hands a little dirtier with the `subprocess` module, rather than using the `os.system()` call.

If you have version 3.5 (or better), this is as simple as:

```
import subprocess as sp
x = sp.run(['7z', 'a', 'junk.7z', 'junk.txt'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
print(x.returncode)
```

That `junk.txt` in my case is a real file but `junk.7z` is just a copy of one of my text files, hence an invalid archive. The output from the program is `2` so it's easily detectable if something went wrong.

If you print out `x` rather than just `x.returncode`, you'll see something like (reformatted and with `\r\n` sequences removed for readability):

```
CompletedProcess(
  args=['7z', 'a', 'junk.7z', 'junk.txt'],
  returncode=2,
  stdout=b'
    7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov 2010-11-18
    Error: junk.7z is not supported archive
    System error:
    Incorrect function.
  '
)
```

Comment: 'os.system()' is a holdover from my debugging process, I was using 'subprocess.call()' in another script to keep the command line quiet. Any ideas in particular, or should I just dig around in the documentation?

Comment: Ah, your edit explaining the code is _very_ helpful, thank you! I'll have to do some reading but will this work for other applications that put out a response code in a similar method to 7-zip?

Comment: @James, yes, it should. If an app returns a code, it's made available to the invoker.